# Putty session start from shortcut on port

Tags: ssh, putty

so I use a shortcut to load a session from user/password on default port like so below:

.\putty.exe root@212.83.***.***-pw PASSWORD

I have changed my SSH port on the server from 22, to something else. How can I make that shortcut load on a port too? like Ex: -port 09?

Also, inside a batch file can I make it load a putty session like so above and send a command?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just append the port after the address? Like `username@address.of.host:09`

Comment: @TheZ I tried that, didn't work. I'll try again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a putty profile in a saved session, and then call it from the command line like:

```
putty.exe -load my_putty_profile
```

It is possible to put ssh remote commands in the profile (under Connection | SSH).

Specify the port in the profile, or alternatively, use the `-P port` command-line argument.

Comment: Thank's but I don't under stand "profile", here is my UI http://i.imgur.com/vpIWe.png

Comment: Ahaha, I'm such a moron, I tried -p port# and it didn't work, but I just tried -P port# (Capital "P") and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: When you start PuTTY from the GUI, you get a PuTTY Configuration dialog.  This is where you have a Category panel that has a lot of configuration options.  If you set up your options, you can save them by going to Session and by creating a Saved Session.  I guess then, in PuTTY terminology, what I am calling a profile is a saved session.  Whatever name you give the saved session is the name put after the `-load` argument.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to view pictures from that domain from my network.  The domain is blocked for me.